# cygwin shell script to PHP

Tags: php, authentication, cygwin

I am attempting to take an existing shell script which runs and executes properly for me under cygwin and rewrite it in PHP.   The part of the script that I am having trouble with simply navigates to a logon page and successfully logs on.

Here is the part of the shell script (that works):

```
curl -s -c "$c" -o gotoLogin.html "https://www.somewebsite.com/account/gotoLogin.action"
curl -s -b "$c" -c "$c" -d 'login_url=' -d 'login_email=someemail@example.com' -d 'login_password=YOURPASSWORD' -d 'login_remember_me=on' -L -o "login_action.html" "https://www.somewebsite.com/account/login.action"
```

here is some php code which attempts to perform the commands above;

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/account/gotoLogin.action';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/account/login.action';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login_url=' . '&login_email=someemail@example.com' . '&login_password=mypassword' . '&login_remember_me=on');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

1.)  It seems the second shell script command references two different URLs.  Looking in Firebug when running the PHP script, I see under the Net/Status column '301 Moved Permanently' for some of the javascript items.  When accessing the actual website the items are found.  So I guess both of the URLs are needed.  I looked around but am not quite sure the easiest way to implement this in PHP.

"login_action.html" "https://www.somewebsite.com/account/login.action"

2.)  When looking at the generated logon form for the actual site, I do not see an input field labeled 'login_url' which seems kind of strange as this Shell script seems to specify the parameter but with no value.

The above PHP code is not working to auto log on to the web site.

Any clues appreciated.

Comment: HTTP 301 is a permanent redirect. It tells the browser that the resource has been permanently moved to a new URL. So, you don't need both URLs.

Comment: That is interesting about the 301.  It also shows them as Size = 0B which doesn't seem right.